# Passing object array from jsp to controller in spring using ajax

Tags: java, spring, jsp

I want to know how can I pass data from jsp to controller in Spring. On this case, my data is array of array having object.

In my company, I have to complete functionality converting contents of jquery datatable(grid) to excel file in Spring(java) + jquery environment.

So, I thought.

1. pass grid data to controller.
2. convert grid data object to excel file.

I have stuck on process 1.

Belows are my code snippets.

1. jsp

```
     $.ajax({
             url: "<c:url value='/storage/testExcel' />", 
             type: "post",
              dataType: "json",
              data: {
              "excel_data" : excel_data
              },
              success: function() {
            alert("success");
            },
            error: function() {
                alert("error in data transfer")
            }
         });
```

2. excel_data form

Oops.. T.T.  I am not able to post image.

It seems like

```
[Array[4], Array[4], Array[4] ... , Array[4]] // It counts 100 things.
```

And a Array[4] has

```
 0: "2015-08-03 11:00:22",

 1: "가",

 2: "su-log",

 3: Object

  datetime: "201508030001",

  hostname: "...",

  pid: "...",

  state: "...",

  userName: "...",

...

  utUser: "..."
```

3. Controller java source

```java
    public class ExcelDatas {
      private List<ExcelData> excelDatas;
      // getters and setters
    }

    public class ExcelData {
      private String date;
      private String host;
      private String type;
      private Map<String, Object> message;

      // getters and setters
    }
```

I have tried `@RequestParam`, `@ModelAttribute`, `@RequestBody`, but I didn't have proper binding. So I didn't proceed.

In any way, I want to manipulate data from jsp. I means that it must not use my model(class ExcelData, class ExcelDatas).

Thank you for reading my question.

Comment: What is the exception you get?
Generally, to upload images you should try `MultipartFile` type and `consumes="multipart/form-data"` instruction.

Comment: It results from my low reputation. To post image, it needs 10 reputation. But  I'm new newbie, so I have no reputation. I mean it ^^;